# Spring WebFlux add WebFIlter to match specific paths

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

In the context of a spring boot application, I am trying to add a WebFilter to filter only requests that match a certain path.

So far, I have a filter:

```
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
                             WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        final ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();

            if (request.getPath().pathWithinApplication().value().startsWith("/api/product")) {
               // logic to allow or reject the processing of the request
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to remove the path matching from the filter and add it somewhere else more suitable, such as, from what I've read so far, a `SecurityWebFilterChain`.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm really interested in a cleaner way to handle the path in webfilter too.

Answer (score 9):

I've, maybe, a cleaner way to address your problem. It's based on code found in [UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/reactive/UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.java). It uses [PathPattern](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a89e716cc71a8741385a0224b5d7eb7ce009e11a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.java) that suits your needs.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final PathPattern pathPattern;

    public AuthenticationFilter() {
        pathPattern = new PathPatternParser().parse("/api/product");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
                         WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    final ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();

        if (pathPattern.matches(request.getPath().pathWithinApplication())) {
           // logic to allow or reject the processing of the request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I add multiple paths?

Comment: @Ilya Y You could define a List of PathPattern that will contain the definition of all your paths.